# I can still find deleted and purged emails in outlook.com

Tags: outlook.com, microsoft-account

Recently I decide to move back to my old MS account from other MS account and take this absolutely clean and organized.
But collide a couple of issues which MS support cannot (or don't want) to explain.

First of them according to sky and contacts is described here: [People and skype contacts not synchronized in Outlook.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/113869/people-and-skype-contacts-not-synchronized-in-outlook-com).

Second issue according to deleted emails is there.

I want to totally cleanup my old and spam emails, and to do this I deleted all emails in all folders on https://outlook.live.com then delete all from deleted items folder.  There is second level allows to restore deleted items and I also purge all items there by office outlook 2016, and now it says clean:

[image]

But...

I still can find any purged email:

[image]

And this my question: can I fix it?

Comment: Search probably looks in an outdated index.

Comment: Found that emails is in IPM_SUBTREE folder,  but even MFCMAPI tool does not show them in this folder.
i can to delete them from search results, but cannot find all of them because wildcard search not supported