# People and Skype contacts not synchronized in Outlook.com

Tags: outlook.com, contacts, skype-for-web

Recently I decided to move back to my old Microsoft account from another Microsoft account and make is absolutely clean and organized. I've run into a couple of issues which MS support cannot (or don't want) to explain.

One of them is that my Contacts are messed up with Skype contacts.

First, I completely deleted all contacts to start from scratch.
After that I purged all deleted contacts. After that I cleaned up Skype contacts in desktop (full) client.

Opening https://outlook.live.com/owa/?path=/people gets me:

[image: screen shot of Outlook.com contacts]

Issues:

- deleted contacts still there
- some of contacts become 'Q'

Next I opened Skype web client on same page:

Issues:

- marked people I do not know
- there are some contacts I never contacted on the internet. (Some kind of spying?)

Next, I click "cleanup contacts" and see:

[image: deleted and purged contacts]

Deleted and purged contacts are still there!

And this my question same: WTF? And can I fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Fixed this by myself by editing and deleting contacts with [MFCAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi/releases/tag/17.0.17099.01) tool.

First you need to connect problem account via Office Outlook on desktop.
Run this tool, and you will be able to browse outlook database and edit it contents

So, for my question i was navigated to "contacts/skype contacts", then find deleted accounts and remove them completely. 
For the Q contacts i found them in the list and fill missing fields same way as other good contacts.

In a few minutes outlook.com synchronized with my changes and show contacts in correct way(for now, but not for future)

MS support was cannot helped there and only able to send bot answers

For full reference of MFCMAPI tool please read [documentation](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi/blob/master/docs/MFCMAPIArticles.md)

Comment: Mention the procedure how did you do that. That would be more helpful to qualify this as an answer.

Comment: @serenesat updated, I did not think it was interesting to anyone because little views and answers